# Lagrangian foliation for a holomorphic symplectic manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, complex-manifolds, symplectic-topology, holomorphic-symplectic

I am interested in gathering as many examples as possible for Lagrangian foliations of holomorphically symplectic manifolds $(X, \omega)$, where $X$ is a $2n$-dimensional complex manifold equipped with a closed non-degenerate (2,0)-form $\omega$ on $X$. A trivial example would be the cotangent bundle of a $n$-dimensional complex manifold. 
Can someone point to a nontrivial example of a Lagrangian foliation for a holomorphically symplectic manifold where one has a "natural" choice of polarisation like in the case of the cotangent bundle? Are there such examples at all? I cannot find any so I wonder. Thanks in advance for your input.

***Edit***: I changed the word "canonical" with "natural" in order to circumvent misunderstandings.

Comment: What do you mean by "a canonical choice of polarisation"?

Comment: Maybe I should have said "natural" choice of a polarization. In the case of a cotangent bundle $T^*X$ at each point $q\in T^*X$ one naturally chooses the kernel of the differential of the projection map $\pi: T^*X\longrightarrow X$ at $q$ as the Lagrangian subspace of $T_q(T^*X)$. This defines a natural Lagrangian foliation on $T^*X$. I wonder if there are other such examples where a preferred foliation like in the simple case of a cotangent bundle exists. Thanks.